# Creating an encrypted text field through metadata deployment - invalid length, maximum is: 255

Tags: deployment, custom-field, metadata-api, encryption, platform-bug

I defined an encrypted text field with a length of 255 and deployed it to my org.

```
<fields>
    <fullName>Field__c</fullName>
    <externalId>false</externalId>
    <label>Field</label>
    <length>255</length>
    <maskChar>asterisk</maskChar>
    <maskType>all</maskType>
    <required>false</required>
    <trackFeedHistory>false</trackFeedHistory>
    <trackHistory>false</trackHistory>
    <trackTrending>false</trackTrending>
    <type>EncryptedText</type>
    <unique>false</unique>
</fields>
```

For some reason, I got an error message saying:

> Object__c.Field__c    Custom Field    73  13  Invalid length, maximum is: 255

although clearly, the field length is set to 255.

[image]

Does anyone know how to resolve this deployment issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maximum length of text encrypted field is 175. Salesforce just shows incorrect error message

you can read it [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_about_encrypted_fields.htm&language=en_US&type=0)

> Are limited to 175 characters because of the encryption algorithm.